# Is there a way to reformat css using vim macros or other tools?

Tags: vim, formatting, css

I have a css file with lines like this:

```
.exhibit-page-nav {list-style:none; float: left; padding: 1em 0; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #c7b5a2;}
```

but I want it to look like this:

```
.exhibit-page-nav {
    list-style:none; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 1em 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    border-top: 1px solid #c7b5a2;
}
```

Is there a way to write a vim macro to do that?

Comment: If you want to use vim, this may solve your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480264/format-css-with-vim-like-in-textmate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user137369's comment is spot on but you asked for a vim macro…

A macro is not needed if you only want to format this single line: a simple substitution is enough. But you may have to do the same exercise again in the future; in this case, you may want to record it as a macro or even save it as a command or a mapping.

So… let's say you want to keep it as a macro:

```
qx              " start recording in register x
:s/[;\{]/\0\r/g " the substitution that does the formatting
=i{             " indent the whole thing nicely
q               " stop recording
```

After that, you can apply the macro by placing your cursor on a ligne and hitting:

```
@x
```

The substitution means "replace any `;` or `{` (`[;\{]`) with itself (`\0`) followed by a carriage return (`\r`)".

Now suppose you have a block of a dozen of such lines, applying your macro to all of them is as simple as selecting them and typing:

```
:'<,'>norm @x
```

See `:help :normal`.

If you have a lot of such lines across the file and are able to identify a common pattern, say `;}`, another option (which I like a lot) would be to use the `:global` command:

```
:g/;\}/norm @x
```

See `:help :global`.